# Use Classes and external py files in Azure functions

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm working with Azure Functions using the HTTP trigger template.

I'm trying to call my classes that are in another file but when I run the code the console shows me an error:

[image]

This is the code that I have:

[image]

[image]

I was searching in the documentation but I found nothing about this.
What could I do to work with my files and their classes?

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you please provide your project folder structure?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to import custom class in Azure Function, we should use explicit relative or absolute references. At the moment, Azure function doesn't support  implicit relative imports of the form `import xxx` from within the project. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#import-behavior)

For example

`__app__` is the function application's top level module and can be used as an anchor for performing absolute imports.

```
__app__
  Function1
    __init__.py
    func_module.py
  HelperCode
    __init__.py
    helper_module.py
```

we can use the following sytaxes (as examples):

1. `from __app__ import HelperCode`
2. `from __app__.HelperCode import helper_module`
3. `import __app__.Function1`
4. `import __app__.HelperCode`

Answer (score 0):

So, in your function app, how are you using helper_module.py and func_module.py if you cannot import from other Python functions?

Here's my understanding -- you have a single Azure Functions app. Within that, you have two Azure functions.

As per usual, you have the **init**.py for each function -- this is where your code lives.

I am therefore not clear on the utility of the func_module.py and the helper_module.py -- does each have the same exact code as in the **init**.py they are below?

OR...are the **init**.py blank with the actual code in the separate .py files below each **init**.py?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, user folder name then your file name while importing, like below given.

[image]